# Build Actions for all classes that mixin a trait

Tags: scala, types, playframework-2.0, traits, boilerplate

Using Scala Play 2.3

I have a collection of model case classes & companions that implement a 
particular trait - DummyData

```
trait DummyData[T] {
  def dummy(idx: Long): T

  def dummy(idxs: List[Long]): List[T] = {
    for {idx <- idxs} yield dummy(idx)
  }
}

case class Location(locationIdx: Long)
case class Vehicle(vehicleIdx: Long, mileage: Long)

object Location extends ...
  with DummyData[Location]
{
  def dummy(idx: Long) = {
    SubscriberLocation(idx, "name-" + idx)
  }
}

object Vehicle extends...
  with DummyData[Vehicle]
{
  ...
}
```

I have corresponding Actions defined in a controller:

```
val dummyIdxs: List[Long] = (1L to 5L).toList

def locationDummy = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Json toJson Provider.dummy(dummyIdxs))
}

def vehicleDummy = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(Json toJson Vehicle.dummy(dummyIdxs))
}
....
```

All but one word of each Action is duplicate code.

I would like to be able to make an Action that provides dummy data for any 
class that mixes in the DummyData trait. So I would have a method defined
like this:

```
def dummyAction[T <: DummyData](modelCompanion: T) = {
  Action { implicit request =>
    Ok(Json toJson modelCompanion.dummy(dummyIdxs))
  }
}
```

or

```
object DummyActionCreator[T] extends (DummyList[T] => TxAction) { 
  def apply(model: DummyList[T]) = TxAction { implicit request =>
    Ok(Json toJson model.dummy(dummyIdxs))
  }
}
```

And then be able to make the new actions by simply calling

```
def locationDummy = dummyAction[Location]
```

or

```
def locationDummy = dummyAction(Location)
```

What is the proper scala feature I should use to achieve this? Do I need to take a step back and change the trait?

I've tried several variations of this, but the error that most often hits me is DummyData needing type parameters. If I could modify the trait so that it doesn't need type parameters, that'd be a welcome solution, but I think it's necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is a feature called "existencial types". You can read a decent explanation (it is not a trivial concept, so I haven't found a magical blog that makes it immediately clear) [here](http://www.drmaciver.com/2008/03/existential-types-in-scala/).

The following code does what you want and prints "3"

```
  trait DummyData[T] {
     def dummy(idx: Long): T

     def dummy(idxs: List[Long]): List[T] = {
        for {idx <- idxs} yield dummy(idx)
     }
  }

  object Test extends DummyData[Int]
  {
     override def dummy(idx: Long): Int = 3
  }

  def dummyAction(modelCompanion: DummyData[T] forSome { type T}) =
  {
     modelCompanion.dummy(3)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
  {
     val dummy3 = dummyAction(Test)
     print(dummy3)
  }
```

Cheers!